# Covering of Klein Bottle by Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I have to show there is a covering of the Klein Bottle by the Torus. I realize this has been answered here: [Two-sheeted covering of the Klein bottle by the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073425/two-sheeted-covering-of-the-klein-bottle-by-the-torus).

However, by the Galois Correspondence we know that covering maps of the Klein Bottle correspond bijectively with subgroups of the fundamental group of the Klein Bottle. If we let $T$ denote the Torus and $K$ the Klein Bottle, then $\pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(K) \cong \langle a,b: abab^{-1} = 1 \rangle$. To show that there is a covering of the Torus by the Klein Bottle would it be enough to show that $\langle a,b: abab^{-1} = 1 \rangle$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? Moreover, if this is the case, is this an easier problem to handle?

Comment: That would only follow if spaces corresponding to certain subgroups were unique up to homeomorphism, which I don't believe is true.

Comment: Doesn't the correspondence tell us that the spaces are unique up to homeomorphism?

Comment: I'm trying to verify that right now.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins It is true: see https://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/872s07/lecnotes/notes2.covering.spaces.pdf end of page 6 to beginning of page 7.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong. See Theorem 1.38 in Hatcher. In fact, more is true. These spaces are not just homeomorphic, but isomorphic as covering spaces. Edit: Sorry, didn't see that you had already found a source.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Okay, is it easy to see that there $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\langle a,b: abab^{-1} = 1\rangle$? I have tried a couple of things but have not found anything, although I do not know if there are any good techniques for a problem like this.

Comment: I would try to work with presentations. $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \langle a,b | ab = ba \rangle$. Does that help?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Eh, I do not know what $a,b$ should be in this presentation

Comment: One subgroup of $\langle a, b\ |\ abab^{-1} = 1\rangle$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b^2$ (indeed $ab^2= b a^{-1} b = b^2 a)$.

Comment: Also, in an answer to a related question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125520/is-there-a-non-trivial-covering-of-the-klein-bottle-by-the-klein-bottle/3125692#3125692) I look at some families of subgroups and show how some give you coverings by tori and others give you coverings by Klein bottles, you may find it useful

Comment: @William Nice! Can you put your comment in the form of an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One subgroup of $\langle a, b\ |\ abab^{-1} = 1 \rangle $ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b^2$. Indeed these elements commute: $ab^2 = ba^{-1}b = b^2 a$, and as this is a finite-index sub-group of a surface group it is also a surface group, so in particular it only has one relation. In general you could take $a^m$ and $b^{2n}$.

In an answer to a related question ([Is there a non-trivial covering of the Klein bottle by the Klein bottle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125520/is-there-a-non-trivial-covering-of-the-klein-bottle-by-the-klein-bottle/3125692#3125692)) I gave a few families of subgroups and determined the total spaces of the corresponding cover space in those cases, maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: I do have a little concern: While I see that $a,b^2$ commute, are you sure that there are no other relations between these two elements. I know that presentations work weird and sometimes there are "hidden" relations. Is there any way to guarantee that doesn't happen here?

Comment: I think we're ok in this case. For any *surface group* $G\cong \pi_1(\Sigma)$ for some surface $\Sigma$, every finite-index subgroup is again a surface group, because it is the fundamental group of a covering space and a covering space of a surface is a surface. In particular, a finite-index subgroup of a surface group will be 1-relator